Retrofit building with bike lift
At work, we lease 4 floors of a building: everything but the ground floor, where there are shops.
We have a loverly bike shed.  It's on the first floor (ie, 22 steps in 3 flights above the ground).  For many reasons, we're losing that floor and the bike shed will be communal space between us and the new tenant(s).
Some of my coworkers are unable to lift their bikes up the stairs, so they've been using the lift (elevator).  This won't be an option in the future.
What can we do to get heavy, large, or awkward bikes up the stairs to the bike shed?

The single stairwell is also a fire escape, so any solutions must not cause us to fail an inspection.  This rules out stair-ramps, as well as anything that intrudes into the stairwell.

At the moment, the preferred solution is one of those stair-lift chairs that are used for elderly or frail people to go up/down stairs.  Still to be resolved is how that would avoid impacting the fire egress requirements.
I personally like the idea of installing a cargo elevator through one piece of floor that overlaps, but that's expensive and wouldn't be rated to carry people nor any cargo above 100 kg.
The other plausible solution is a cage outside in the carpark, and we lose the internal space.  But that's cold, wet, and relatively low-security, so not my ideal.

If using the lift won't be allowed in the future, and the stairwell either, I don't see other options than taking on parking space, using the argumentation that bikes require less space than cars, so that would be a net gain - if parking spots are not a "privilege".

What are the accessibility (legal) requirements where you are? If you need to be able to get disabled staff/customers/visitors to a nearby bit of the building you might be able to piggy back on that. Of course if you've been dumped in a basement that doesn't need much other access, you wouldn't get very far with that argument

@renaud The lift still works but we can only exit to our floors, 3 and 4.  The level
1 tenancy space is between the lift and the bikeshed space, so we'd have to wheel a bike through someone else's office to get to the shared bikeshed.  That won't be allowed, it would be like walking through your neighbour's house.

@ChrisH good thought - but there are no customers.  The bike shed is a nice convenient sheltered dry and warm space for bikes we can use, but its not part of the space we lease.  Its like the foyer or the stairwell in being shared with other tenants.   The problem is 3~5 vocal people who have heavy ebikes or are not able to lift their regular bikes up the stairs.   ~50 other users can do this well-enough.   I just hope we don't loose the bike shed completely because "its too hard"

It's tricky in this case. I guess accessibility for staff is something they'd address if they ever hired someone - and that will mysteriously never happen. In public(ish) infrastructure I strongly support those who can't lift their bikes, including those who ride e-bikes as something approaching a mobility aid.  These are often the same people who don't physically have the option to walk (and therefore are limited in their use of public transport).

Is there an option for a small cage in the car park - or perhaps better, bike lockers - for those whose bikes are too heavy for the stairs? Though lockers rule out trikes and odd-shaped bikes

I though about a stair rail, on the floor, for bikes, but that intrudes into the stairwell

Exterior cable lift (like window cleaners but maybe minus platform) and bust a bike sized hole in the exterior wall ?? Keyed/PIN access to up/down controls so you don’t need to leave your bike unattended while you travel up and down floors.

Stair lifts are super slow. I also think that proper parking on the ground is the best solution. My employer has a locked bicycle room in the parking garage which you can only enter with company ID card. If there is no room available at your employer, maybe something similar could be implemented with a shipping container. At the very least you should have some strong ground anchors or rails to which you can lock the bike.

I suspect this question is outside the scope of what bicycles SE can realistically answer. Although there might be some creative discussion here, realistically you're looking at hiring an engineering consultant (especially if you're doing this formally and up to code). For one, there's a lot of information missing before any technical discussion can begin--does the boss approve of this project, what's the budget and timeframe, are you allowed to perform significant construction, what are the relevant building codes (I take that to be NZ), just how formal/proper is this supposed to be, etc.

@ChrisH  It is a cop-out but the company isn't required to provide indoor bike storage, regardless if the staff are ablebodied or not.

@Michael shipping container - that's brilliant !  Can you add that as an answer?

@Criggie of course, that's why it's tricky here and why I wondered about any requirements they do have that you could leverage. TBH I think outdoors,  with some security and some protection from the weather, is already about as far as most employers can be pushed

Check if these boxes are available where you live. They usually fit in a single car parking space and are easy to install. How many bikes are there, anyway?

@berend there are three users who can't/won't carry up the stairs, out of about 50 riders.  This is a Good idea - add it as an answer please ?

Done. I can't seem to find anything outside The Netherlands or Belgium, but who knows.

If you don't need to store too many bicycles, you could check if these kind of boxes are available where you live. They usually fit in a single car parking space and are easy to install.
Other than the more traditional bicycle lockers, they fit multiple bikes (2 - 6 seems to be common), so possibly less space per bike would be needed.
Example from Velobox (not affiliated):


That specific example seems  rather lacking in security.  Shared bike storage really needs something solid to lock each bike to by the frame (this also makes it less likely that people will drop bikes on each other), as well as a lock on the whole store.  Would you trust all your colleagues to lock the store securely and not leave your bike at risk?

@ChrisH they seem to work good enough where I live. YMMV

Use a rail on the stairs, like I see on train stations in europe (see example). E-bikes usually have a walk mode to help push them up the rail

That is a good idea and if it were a simple staircase that would be perfect.   Downside is this stairwell is also classed as a fire escape so there must be nothing that can impede egress.   A rail on the stairs would have to be at least 30 cm out from the wall and that places it firmly in the walking part of the tread and would be a trip hazard.   A ramp that folds up when not in use might work.

Is it a typical commercial hand railing anchored to the wall instead of the stair treads?  If it is, the bicycle ramp could be installed under the hand railing against the wall. The bike would have to be leaned while pushing but it would not impact the usable width of the stair tread

@mikes that's an excellent thought - We're going to give some ideas a try tomorrow, in the rough to see what might be workable.

The rails on most Dutch stairs are placed very close to the wall, you hold your bike at an angle, wheels away from you, to use them.

FINAL PRODUCT:



Perfect length fitment !

RESULTS:

It's too steep, at 32.3 degrees ramp matches the stairs.
You have to lean your bike, but its really easy to clang pedals into the Baluster and Newel posts.
The breakover angle at the top is a bit abrupt - so its possible for longer/lower bikes to strike a chainring.
There's not a lot of room on the landing to line-up.

And the final blow is that someone descending the stairs may stand on the ramp and fall.
This kills the idea of ramps dead.

Older
Summary:
Lifts are too expensive - likely to be $20k NZ minimum and that's just a cargo platform, not able to carry a person.  Landlord has also rejected the idea.
A stair-motor-chair is on the table still, but only because we haven't had a price.
I've started a proof-of-concept on the smallest flight with four steps:



I can't add the other three props without accurate measurements, so will do that at work.  I could not bring the stairs home for a test-fit, and I didn't think to do a tracing on a large piece of paper/cardboard.
An outdoor cage is the last resort.

Criggie, You are a capable person; I'm sure an external to the building pulley system could be made to work. If I knew how, this would have been an answer.

@Vorac good idea - but there are no opening windows or patios because its an office block.   That would work for someone at home
